# React Navigation without import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

We created React Native app with React navigation but forgot to add
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

App casually displays blank screen in production.
Is there any chance that missing import of 'react-native-gesture-handler' could lead to such behaviour?

We trying to investigate issue.
But managers require to find the root cause.